# Create image of laptop when laptop keeps switching off

Tags: backup

**Background**: A working Lenovo Thinkpad laptop, Ubuntu 18.04.5, Intel i5 dual core M480 @ 2.67Ghz,  8mb RAM, SSD 250 gb. Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. My only machine. I have had an 'expert' replace thermal paste and clean the fan, but the machine continues to switch off due to an overheating CPU (I have monitored its temperature). Despite buying a cooling pad too. Mainly use Ubuntu but this is a business machine for accounts and tax etc., and I need to refer to history in Windows 7.

**Project:** Take system image first of all; resize hard-drive partitions as only 200mb left for Ubuntu, upgrade to Ubuntu 20.4, replace motherboard (to be obtained second hand) as appears to be reason for overheating/ switching off.

**Advice needed:** Cannot see how to start project as unable to take system image due to always overheating/ switching off mid-save to external 1 TB hard drive. And want to play safe, all on-line advice is to take such a backup beforehand. Would reducing CPU clock speed reduce overheating? I suppose one alternative is to take out the SSD drive and copy this via my Clone  A to B kit. What would you suggest please?

Comment: I can advise you to make a backup with rsync of the whole Ubuntu system and then the Windows one. If you have another backup PC and an external disk available, I would recommend using [Butterfly Backup](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/Butterfly-Backup) on both systems. This would allow you to work remotely without loading the disk IO and CPU, so as not to overheat the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If running dd over to a new device is not possible within the current hardware due to the power offs, the method you mentioned sounds like the best way to continue. Move the disk to a new device and dd it over there instead.